# C++ MFC: How to open immediately a secondary dialog after the first modal dialog was created

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

how can I open a secondary modal dialog in C++ MFC from a dialog without pressing any button?
(If I create a dialog in OnInitDialog(), the first dialog won't appear.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);` in your OnInitDialog just before display the secondary dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. The reason was because of a problem in clear case which made the sln folder unreachable. Try close/stop ClearCase and open it again. Browse to the folder from clearcase and open the .sln.

Good Luck